# Multivariate approximation - interpolating polynomial

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

How many points uniquely determine the interpolating polynomial of degree at most $d$ if there are $k$ variables?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What is your answer for very small limiting cases?

Comment: For two variables,
$$p(x, y) = (a_0) + (a_1 x + a_2 y) + (a_3 x^2 + a_4 x y + a_5y^2) + \cdots$$
and for three variables, 
$$p(x, y, z) = (a_0) + (a_1 x + a_2 y + a_3 z) + (a_4x^2 + a_5 xy + a_6 xz + a_7 y^2 + a_8 yz + a_9 z^2) + \cdots$$ Look for the pattern in the number of degrees of freedom available. As @DavidG.Stork suggests, write out a few more to see what things look like.